# firebase-admin send FCM to specific android using device token as authentication

Tags: firebase-admin

Hello guys I am using firebase-admin, it works fine sending and receiving using notification topics, however our project requires to send FCM to specific android device using device token. I can't find example in the repository of firebase-admin

Answer (score 0):

Several examples available at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-specific-devices